# О реформировании русского языка

Tags: реформа

9 июня 2014 года В.В. Путин образовал Совет при Президенте Российской Федерации по русскому языку.

Вопрос: Какие предложения по реформированию русского языка вы готовы внести на рассмотрение указанного консультативного органа [при Президенте Российской Федерации]?

Answer (score 1):

ДЛЯ СПРАВОК

1) У Совета будет ТРИ ОСНОВНЫЕ ЗАДАЧИ:

а)ПОДГОТОВКА ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЙ президенту России по определению приоритетных направлений и механизмов развития, защиты и поддержки русского языка в РФ и за рубежом;

б) КООРДИНАЦИЯ деятельности органов государственной власти и местного самоуправления, общественных объединений и разного рода организаций по вопросам, связанным с развитием, защитой и поддержкой русского языка;

в)АНАЛИЗ РЕАЛИЗАЦИИ программ и проектов, расширение географии и сферы применения русского языка, поддержка русскоязычных сообществ за рубежом.

2) За последние 20 лет количество говорящих в мире на русском языке снизилось на 120 млн человек. Сейчас это 260 млн, в том числе порядка 140 млн человек на территории России.
С 7 декабря 1995 года по 23 мая 1997 год при президенте России в качестве консультативного органа уже существовал Совет по русскому языку (с примерно такими же задачами). В  1997 году  Ельцин упраздняет Совет.  Причина — совершенствование системы совещательных и консультативных органов при Президенте РФ.

ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЕ

а) Создать общественное объединение russ.hashcode.ru. для подготовки предложений в области правописания. б)Обеспечить его координацию с разными органами.в) Создать банк предложений.

С моей точки зрения, важны три идеи:

А)  Наша система правописания должна соответствовать Правилам 1956 года и дальнейшему их дополнению под ред. Розенталя, то есть по существу не должна меняться.

Б) При это надо составить новую редакцию Правил 1956 года, в которой все правила объяснить, подвести под теоретический базис  и систематизировать. К примеру, в области пунктуации хорошо бы создать Каталог применяемых грамматических форм для каждой темы (однородные члены, сложные предложения и др.) по схеме: индекс/номер - название грамматической формы - знаки препинания - примеры из классической и современной литературы.

В) Все нововведения в орфографию после 2000 года тщательно рассмотреть на предмет расхождения с прежней орфографией и исключить "двоевластие" в правописании.

Comment: Дорогая София.

Я не возражаю, чтобы Ваша "система правописания" "соответствовала Правилам 1956 года и дальнейшему их дополнению под ред. Розенталя".

Comment: Согласна. Готова присоединиться.

Answer (score 0):

Да, Вы правы,София. В сегодняшней орфографии большой разнобой.